Resources on Phase Ordering Dynamics and Non-Linear System
I am doing a course on Non-Equilibrium Physics. Prof. was initially following Strogatz but has now started teaching Phase ordering dynamics, Cahn-Hillard equation and all?
I can't seem to find a good book for this. I asked GPT but some recommendations don't even contain the Cahn-Hillard (lol). So please recommend something that discusses the above topics in decent amount of depth, something related to soft matter or biophysics is preferred as the prof's work is in that field and I am interested in reading more about it.

Non equilibrium statistical mechanics by Livi and Politi has a quite clear but succint chapter about phase ordering and coarsening

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/827356/2451 and links therein.
