Nonlinear physics
Hey I wanna start studying nonlinear physics, and to be honest I don't know from where to start, I need books for beginners that explains things in general about the nonlinear science branches, so please if anyone knows can you recommend good books

What is your background in physics?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is an immense field, and analytical results are few and far between.   How much computing power can you access?

Classification of mathematical problems as linear and nonlinear is like classification of the Universe as bananas and non-bananas. (Network Humor, source unknown). -- https://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/quotes.html

@Andrew This is hilarious. And the point is valid. But on a second look one realizes that physics overwhelmingly deals with linear or near-linear problems. We just have very little idea of what to do when things are not linear. Sidney Coleman put it most candidly: "Theoretical physics is defined as a set of courses each of which discusses harmonic oscillator" (yes, precisely this way. No specific mentions of young physicists, nor their careers: https://youtu.be/PN46bztKuPs?si=sqSArU-mn-Wq2f4k&t=2164). So bananas or not, that's what we do in physics.

Study kinematics at first, there will be your first non-linear experience as per non-linear $x(t)$ definition : $x=x_0+v_0t+at^2/2$. As in a general sense, system where output variable responds not proportionally to some input variable change (in this case change of time $\Delta t$) is a non-linear one. Secondly,- for fully understanding non-linear systems,- you must at first get a very good grasp on linear ones. No pun intended.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer I'm physics student about to start the 3rd year

@ZeroTheHero well I'm still learning Mathematica, would you recommend things will help me?

A reasonable place to start could be

Strogatz, Steven H. "Nonlinear dynamics and chaos: with applications to physics, biology, chemistry, and engineering", (Studies in Nonlinearity) (2001).

It covers the required theory and does contain some exercises, but it's already 20+ years old so obviously the numerical exercises require only minimum computing power.
